# my app post header is gray and the name and app name is not clickable

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

i have an app that post to an action. 
before i submitted the action all was good, after it has been approved when the app post the action on the timeline like : 
Alon Conduri and Expressio App played the same game on Icy Tower.
so the name(Alon Conduri) and the app name(Icy Tower) should be colored blue and clickable.
but its all gray and nothing is clickable.
i really don't know what to do as i didn't change anything and suddenly it has changed.
this is the code i use:

```
var message = {
                "access_token":response.authResponse.accessToken,
                'game': APP_PATH + "movie12.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(APP_PATH + "movie12.php") // http://cap1dev.conduit-apps.com/Apps/gil/icyTowerFacebook/movie12.html"


            };
            //alert(APP_PATH + "movie12.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(APP_PATH + "movie12.php"));
            FB.api('/me/conduit_icytower:play', 'post', message, function (response) {
```

Please help me.

Thanks,